# Raise trigger for duplicate prevention

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, sql-insert, raiserror

I am trying to raise a trigger if duplicate is being inserted into the table `movie_cast$`. But the error is not being raised even if duplicate is being inserted. This is the stored procedure and trigger. Please help.

```
create or alter procedure up_cast_actor
    @actor_id integer,
    @mov_id integer,
    @role_Name varchar(122)
as
begin
    set nocount on

    insert into movie_cast$
        values (@actor_id, @mov_id, @role_name);
end;
go

create or alter trigger prevent_recast 
on movie_cast$ 
after update 
as
begin
    set nocount on

    if exists (
        select *
        from movie_cast$ as t
        inner join inserted i on
            i.mov_id = t.mov_id
            and i.act_id = t.act_id
            and i.role = t.role
    )
    begin
        --rollback
        raiserror( -20001, -1,-1, 'This actor is already cast for this movie.'); --to restrict the insetion`.   
        RAISERROR ('Duplicate Data', 16, 1);
        
    end;
end;
go

EXECUTE up_cast_actor 124, 921, 'raj';
EXECUTE up_cast_actor 124, 928, 'rob';
EXECUTE up_cast_actor 124, 921, 'raj';
```

Comment: Why use a `TRIGGER` at all? This is what `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`s and/or `UNIQUE INDEX`es are for.

Comment: And the records will already exist in `movie_cast$` when the trigger runs, so when written correctly it will always be showing duplicates. Also you should mostly be using `THROW` not `RAISERROR`. And best practice is to list the columns being inserted into.

Comment: `alter procedure up_cast_actor` What does "up" mean here? Your procedure is simply INSERTING a single row. In addition, your trigger will not execute for INSERTS at all - only for UPDATES.  Lastly, your error message is misleading as the wording is singular - a trigger executes at a statement level which can affect many (or even none) rows.

Comment: And new code should use THROW rather than RAISERROR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First : you forget a ROLLBACK statement to cancel the transaction

Second : you forget to count (HAVING)

Third : you do no have the right syntax for RAISERROR

The code must be :

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER prevent_recast 
ON movie_cast$ 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   movie_cast$ as t
                      JOIN inserted i 
                         ON i.mov_id = t.mov_id
                            AND i.act_id = t.act_id
                            AND i.role = t.role
               HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
RETURN;
ROLLBACK;
RAISERROR('Duplicate Data : this actor is already cast for this movie.', 16, 1);
GO
```

Of course as @Larnu says, this is a stupid thing to do a cancel on a transaction that is made of interpreted code (Transact SQL) and runs after the INSERT, instead of using a UNIQUE constraints that runs in C language and acts before the insert !

The constraint will be as simple as:

```
ALTER TABLE movie_cast$
   ADD UNIQUE (actor_id, mov_id, role_name);
```

*Please **DO NOT** modify my code... Just suggests some corections*

Comment: I don't agree with the fact the OP "forgot" the `ROLLBACK`. The OP shouldn't be using `ROLLBACK` in a trigger in the first place. Instead they should be `THROW`ing an error and the outer transaction should be handling the `ROLLBACK`. Using a `ROLLBACK` inside a `TRIGGER` causes an additional (unnecessary) error which can actually make the problem more confusing; especially if something like the calling application presents the wrong error and so the bespoke error isn't presented to the end user.

Comment: Thank you very much @SQLpro. and personally even i would prefer the alter table solution. But it was a specific requirement to use stored procedure and/or triggers that's the reason i tried this way.

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in the comments, using a `TRIGGER` for this doesn't make sense when there's a specific object type for this: `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`.

```sql
--Sample Table
CREATE TABLE dbo.MovieCast (CastID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                            ActorID int NOT NULL,
                            MovieID int NOT NULL,
                            RoleName nvarchar(50));
GO
--Add Constraint
ALTER TABLE dbo.MovieCast ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_MovieActor_MovieCast UNIQUE (ActorID,MovieID);
GO
--Sample Attempts
INSERT INTO dbo.MovieCast (ActorID,
                           MovieID,
                           RoleName)
VALUES(124, 921, 'raj'); --Success
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.MovieCast (ActorID,
                           MovieID,
                           RoleName)
VALUES(124, 928, 'rob'); --Success
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.MovieCast (ActorID,
                           MovieID,
                           RoleName)
VALUES(124, 921, 'Jon'); --Fails
GO
--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.MovieCast;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Larnu . the reason for using a trigger and stored procedure was because this was specifically asked to be done. But yes this solution is much better, cleaner and more importantly faster.

Comment: If, for some reason this is explicitly required (I assume therefore this is homework) you should have explicitly noted that in the question, @KarthikB .

Answer (score 0):

In response to the OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71480510/raise-trigger-for-duplicate-prevention/71480842#comment126344967_71480842):

> the reason for using a trigger and stored procedure was because this was specifically asked to be done.

A `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`/`UNIQUE INDEX` is the right solution here, and it will very likely be much faster. That being said, you can do this with a `TRIGGER` and `THROW` the error to the calling SQL.

```sql
--Sample Table
CREATE TABLE dbo.MovieCast (CastID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                            ActorID int NOT NULL,
                            MovieID int NOT NULL,
                            RoleName nvarchar(50));
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_UQ_MovieActor_MovieCast ON dbo.MovieCast
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM dbo.MovieCast MC
               GROUP BY MC.ActorID, MC.MovieID
               HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
       THROW 55555, --Use a bespoke error number for your environment
             N'A duplicate row has been detected in the trigger ''trg_UQ_MovieActor_MovieCast''. Cannot insert/update duplicate row in object ''dbo.MovieCast''.',
             16; 
END;
GO
--Sample Attempts
INSERT INTO dbo.MovieCast (ActorID,
                           MovieID,
                           RoleName)
VALUES(124, 921, 'raj'); --Success
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.MovieCast (ActorID,
                           MovieID,
                           RoleName)
VALUES(124, 928, 'rob'); --Success
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.MovieCast (ActorID,
                           MovieID,
                           RoleName)
VALUES(124, 921, 'Jon'); --Fails
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MovieCast;
GO
--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.MovieCast;
```

Note that unlike a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`, you aren't informed of the row that causes the error, which means for statements where you affect multiple rows, this will make debugging a little harder.

*Separate answer, as the requirement for needing a `TRIGGER` was never voiced in the question, and my original answer answers the question that was originally asked.*

*Also, although similar to [SQLPro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71480905), I disagree with their use of `RAISERROR` and `ROLLBACK`, and so I am showing how `THROW` should be used.*